# Creating Java code for a SOAP message that reproduces a Soap Request example

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am trying to create a client for a Web Service that gets an int[] as input and as an output.
I found a sample of a Soap Request that shows how the SoapRequest can transfer an Array with Xml.

```
<element name="myFavoriteNumbers"
        type="SOAP-ENC:Array"/>

<myFavoriteNumbers
  SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:int[2]">
   <number>3</number> 
   <number>4</number> 
</myFavoriteNumbers>
```

My code until now

```
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage sm = mf.createMessage();
SOAPHeader sh = sm.getSOAPHeader();
sh.setPrefix("S");
SOAPEnvelope envelope = sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
envelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(envelope.getPrefix());
envelope.setPrefix("S");
          envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("S",
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
SOAPBody sb = sm.getSOAPBody();
sb.setPrefix("S");           
SOAPElement container=sb.addChildElement("sum", "ns2",  webServicePkg);         
SOAPElement a = container.addChildElement("number1");
a.addTextNode(Integer.toString(arg1));
SOAPElement b = container.addChildElement("number2");
b.addTextNode(Integer.toString(arg2));
```

All i need is to transform my current SoapMessage so it can reproduce the Example of Xml given so it can send this 2 numbers as an array and not each one apart.

Thank you very much

Comment: i would imagine that an `int[]` and a "for" loop should do the trick.

Comment: you must add multiple childs of the same element elements.

Comment: Why don't use some client generator? If you don't know any, use netbeans or eclipse.

Comment: its not the <number> </number> that i cant reproduce its the         <element name="myFavoriteNumbers" 
         type="SOAP-ENC:Array"/>         <myFavoriteNumbers
  SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:int[2]">